# Updating column in tableviwer

Tags: swt

I have retrieved data from database and i am able to show it in Table of the Table Viewer but my task is on click of a row the data should be appear in another form from where i can edit it and on click of update the view should be updated with the new values.I am using viewer.addSelectionChangedListener to retrieve the selected row but i am not getting how to update the table .Please suggest me few ideas

I have written the below code in the constructor of my class so whenever object is created Table is generated and l1 is list of data which i am passing to another UI

```
input[i] = new MyModel(persons[i].getDateOfRegistration(), persons[i].getFirstName(),
                persons[i].getMiddleName(), persons[i].getLastName(), persons[i].getGender(),
                persons[i].getDob(), persons[i].getContactNumber(), persons[i].getMaritalStatus(),
                persons[i].getAddress(), persons[i].getCountry(), persons[i].getBloodGroup(),
                persons[i].getInsuranceDetails().getPolicyHolderName(),
                persons[i].getInsuranceDetails().getPolicyNumber(),
                persons[i].getInsuranceDetails().getSubscriberName(),
                persons[i].getInsuranceDetails().getRelationshipToPatient());
    viewer.setInput(input);

    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    GridData gridData = new GridData();
    gridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
    gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
    gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    viewer.getControl().setLayoutData(gridData);
    viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
            IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Selection - ");

            int j = 0;
            String[] s;
            for (Iterator iterator = selection.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

                sb.append(iterator.next() + ", ");
                System.out.println("Testing::" + sb);

            }
            System.out.println(sb);
            String result[] = new String[18];
            List l1 = new ArrayList(100);
            String[] parts = sb.toString().split("=");
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("s" + parts[i]);
                String[] s1 = parts[i].split(",");
                l1.add(s1[0]);
            }
            SWTPatientRegistrationUpdatePageEventView swtPatientRegistrationUpdatePageEventView = new SWTPatientRegistrationUpdatePageEventView();
         swtPatientRegistrationUpdatePageEventView.openParentUpdateShell(l1);
        // viewer.refresh();
            //flag=false;
            //refreshingData(list);

        }
    });
```

Comment: You use table cell editors and the EditingSupport class for this, see [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html)

Comment: Is keeping the entire constructor won't create any issue? Should i keep separate class for setting content and table viewer or its fine if i continue the way i am doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure we will follow table viewer MVC architecture all the time. Steps we can do to resolve your issue isas follow:

1. Create proper datastructure(Model Class) to hold the data. and use the same in array which you set in viewer.setInput()
2. When you click/double click on table row, fetch the data and save it in datastructure created(with new object).
3. Pass that data structure to your form dialog.
4. when you are done with update in form. Fill the updated data in new Model object again.
5. And after form close, pass that model object back to parent.
6. updated the corresponding array element with object received from Form Dialog  and just refresh the tableviewer.

Please let me know if you need some code module. Thanks